# kde on virtualbox already running gnome?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, kde, vmware

What is the smartest/easiest way to get KDE installed on a VM that is already running GNOME?

Would it be better to create a complete new VM just for KDE (because they don't work well together?)

If the best way to do this is in fact to create a new VM, on virtualbox the only Ubuntus that it has is 32 and 64 bit, it does not specify gnome or kde, it just defaults I think to gnome.

Thanks so much for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the smartest/easiest way to get KDE installed on a VM that is already running GNOME?

```
 sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop (non Kubuntu settings)
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop (Kubuntu)
```

1. Plasma Desktop: *Provides the environment for running and managing applications and integrating
   interaction of applications. It is designed as generic environment for all
   kinds of desktop applications, not only applications built on the KDE Platform.
   It integrates best with applications following the standards used by the KDE
   Platform.*
2. Kubuntu Desktop: *This package depends on all of the packages in the Kubuntu desktop system.
   Installing this package will include the default Kubuntu Plasma Desktop or
   Netbook installation.
   It is safe to remove this package if some of the desktop system packages are
   not desired.*

This package is part of the KDE base workspace module.

> Would it be better to create a complete new VM just for KDE (because they don't work well together?)

No, they perfectly work together.

> If the best way to do this is in fact to create a new VM, on virtualbox the only Ubuntus that it has is 32 and 64 bit, it does not specify gnome or kde, it just defaults I think to gnome.

No, VM's default to whatever you have installed on them.

Comment: thanks so much! for my purposes should i go with plasma or kubuntu? i do not understand the difference

Comment: and i would be able to use the programs i installed on gnome on kubuntu as well?

Comment: and how would i toggle between the two systems

Comment: Yes, you can use GTK software on KDE an Viceversa. To change between sessions log out select the session you want and log in.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/images/kdeoneiric03.png) :)

Comment: @EvandroSilva Error 404: The page you were looking for is missing.
If you're not automatically redirected within four seconds, please click here to go to our main page.

Comment: @UriHerrera here's the message i got when i tried to start with plasma:

Comment: call to inusertempfailed check your installation

Comment: Try [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/call-to-lnusertemp-failed-944505/).

Comment: my tmp is not full

Comment: this is what i get when i do df -kh: http://pastebin.com/i9hdMMyQ

Comment: I think you should ask another question about that, it's getting off topic here.

Comment: well you say that they should perfectly work together?

Comment: Yes and that shouldn't have happened that is a different issue. One that I've never seen by the way.